# How to disable select-on-release right mouse button in Linux

Tags: linux, xorg, x11, mouse

We are having issues with mouse behavior in Linux.

In Windows:

In any application, to open a context menu and select an option:

1. right mouse button down + release
2. move the cursor to an option
3. left mouse button down + release

In Linux, the same thing can be done in:

1. right mouse button down
2. move the cursor over to an option
3. release right mouse button.

We are having problems in Eclipse, when accessed from a remote X server on Windows. The padding between the Eclipse menu items and the mouse cursor is too low (mouse cursor is inside the menu). Whenever we press the right mouse button down, mouse cursor is already moved over onto the immediate menu option, and when we release, selection event is triggered.

How to disable this behavior?

Comment: Are you using VNC to share desktop? If else, probably could you try using it, or even another version/implementation

Comment: What X server software are you using on your Windows box?

Comment: I am having the similar problem with VNC (tightVNC/ realVNC), and  I tried different X servers such as Xming, MobaXterm. I think tightVNC and MobaXterm are based on Cygwin's X server for Windows.